Attempting to create a local .NET COM server instance fails with error 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)
I have self-registering local .NET COM server x64 for Windows written in C# and simple COM client written in C++.
Solution repo
The server creates all necessary registry entries and registers the COM class using the IClassFactory implementation. The client call CoCreateInstance for COM class and interface which returns CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE. Windows Event log register error with event code 10010 (Server did not register with DCOM within the required timeout).
Local server implementation:
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using static NetComServer.Helpers.Win32Helper;
using static NetComServer.Helpers.RegistryHelper;
using static NetComServer.Helpers.EnvironmentHelper;
using static NetComServer.ComServerConstants;
using static NetComServer.ComLocalServer;
using IClassFactory = NetComServer.Helpers.Win32Helper.IClassFactory;
using WriteLineDelegate = NetComServer.Helpers.WriteLineDelegate;

return NetComServer.Program.Main(args);

namespace NetComServer
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int exitCode = -1;
            string[]? arguments = string.Join("", args)?.ToLower()?.Split(['/', '-'], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
            Update = arguments?.Contains("update") == true;
            KeepConsole = arguments?.Contains("keepconsole") == true;
            if(arguments?.Contains("unregister") == true)
            {
                exitCode = UnRegisterServer() ? 0 : -1;
            }
            else if(Update || arguments?.Contains("register") == true)
            {
                exitCode = RegisterServer() ? 0 : -1;
            }
            else
            {
                ComLocalServer localServer = new ComLocalServer();
                WriteLine("NetComServer is running...");
                exitCode = localServer.RegisterClassObject() ? 0 : -1;
                WriteLine("RegisterClassObject is " + (exitCode == 0 ? "successeed." : "failed."));
                if(exitCode == 0)
                {
                    localServer.IsServerRunning = true;
                    Thread threadRunServer = new Thread(localServer.Run);
                    WriteLine("Message loop is start.");
                    MSG msg;
                    while(GetMessage(out msg, nint.Zero, 0, 0) > 0)
                    {
                        TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                        DispatchMessage(ref msg);
                    }
                    WriteLine("Message loop is end.");
                    exitCode = localServer.UnRegisterClassObject() ? 0 : -1;
                    WriteLine("UnRegisterClassObject is " + (exitCode == 0 ? "successeed." : "failed."));
                    WriteLine("Wait for server stop...");
                    localServer.IsServerRunning = false;
                    localServer.ServerStopEvent.WaitOne();
                    localServer.ServerStopEvent.Reset();
                    WriteLine("Server is stoped.");
                }
                if(HasConsole)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    if(!KeepConsole)
                    {
                        FreeConsole();
                    }
                }
            }
            return exitCode;
        }
    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid(CLSID_Factory)]
    public class ComServerClassFactory : IClassFactory
    {
        public int QueryInterface([In] ref Guid riid, [Out] out nint ppvObject)
        {
            int hr = S_OK;
            ppvObject = nint.Zero;
            string? strIId = riid.ToString()?.ToUpper()?.Trim();
            switch(strIId)
            {
            case IID_IComServer:
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject<ComServerClassFactory, IComServer>(this);
                hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                break;
            case IID_IClassFactory:
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject<ComServerClassFactory, IClassFactory>(this);
                hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                break;
            case IID_IDispatch:
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(this);
                hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                break;
            case IID_IUnknown:
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(this);
                hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                break;
            default:
                hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
                break;
            }
            return hr;
        }
        public int CreateInstance([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] nint pUnkOuter, [In] ref Guid riid, [Out] out nint ppvObject)
        {
            int hr = S_OK;
            ppvObject = nint.Zero;
            if(pUnkOuter == nint.Zero)
            {
                string? strIId = riid.ToString()?.ToUpper()?.Trim();
                switch(strIId)
                {
                case IID_IComServer:
                    ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject<ComServer, IComServer>(new ComServer());
                    hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                    break;
                case IID_IDispatch:
                    ppvObject = Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(new ComServer());
                    hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                    break;
                case IID_IUnknown:
                    ppvObject = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(new ComServer());
                    hr = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
                    break;
                default:
                    hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hr = CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION;
            }
            return hr;
        }
        public int LockServer([In] bool fLock)
        {
            return S_OK;
        }
    }
    public class ComLocalServer : IDisposable
    {
        public static ReadLineDelegate? ReadLine { get; set; }
        public static WriteLineDelegate? WriteLine { get; set; }
        private static uint ClassId;
        private bool isRunning = false;
        public bool IsServerRunning
        {
            get
            {
                lock(this)
                {
                    return isRunning;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                lock(this)
                {
                    value = isRunning;
                }
            }
        }
        public static bool Update { get; set; } = false;
        public static bool HasConsole { get; set; } = false;
        public static bool KeepConsole { get; set; } = false;
        private bool disposed = false;
        public ManualResetEvent ServerStopEvent { get; set; } = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public ComLocalServer()
        {
            HasConsole = HasConsole || ShowConsole(true);
            WriteLine = HasConsole ? Console.WriteLine : new WriteLineDelegate((string? message) => Debug.WriteLine(message));
            ReadLine = HasConsole ? Console.ReadLine : null;
        }
        public static bool RegisterServer()
        {
            bool isRegistered = false;
            try
            {
                string strPublishDirectory = GetPublishDirectory(typeof(ComLocalServer));
                string strModuleName = typeof(ComLocalServer).Module.Name.Replace(".dll", ".exe");
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strModuleName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strPublishDirectory))
                {
                    string strServerPath = Path.Combine(strPublishDirectory, strModuleName);
                    isRegistered = ComServer.RegisterServer(strServerPath, Update, KeepConsole);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                isRegistered = false;
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            return isRegistered;
        }
        public static bool UnRegisterServer()
        {
            bool isUnregistered = false;
            try
            {
                isUnregistered = ComServer.UnregisterServer(KeepConsole);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                isUnregistered = false;
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            return isUnregistered;
        }
        public bool RegisterClassObject()
        {
            Guid clsidComServer = new Guid(CLSID_ComServer);
            ComServerClassFactory factory = new ComServerClassFactory();
            bool isRegistered = CoRegisterClassObject(ref clsidComServer, factory, CLSCTX.LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS.MULTIPLEUSE | REGCLS.SUSPENDED, out ClassId) == S_OK;
            if(isRegistered)
            {
                isRegistered = CoResumeClassObjects() == S_OK;
            }
            return isRegistered;
        }
        public bool UnRegisterClassObject()
        {
            return ClassId == 0 || CoRevokeClassObject(ClassId) == S_OK;
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            while(IsServerRunning)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            ServerStopEvent.Set();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(!disposed)
            {
                if(disposing)
                {
                    UnRegisterClassObject();
                    if(HasConsole && !KeepConsole)
                    {
                        FreeConsole();
                    }
                }
                disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

COM client:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);
        if(!FAILED(hr))
        {
            IComServer* pComServer = NULL;
            HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ComServer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IComServer, (LPVOID*)&pComServer);
            if(!FAILED(hr) && pComServer != NULL)
            {
                BSTR lpwszAssembly = SysAllocString(L"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\forumengine\\ForumEngine.dll");
                BSTR lpwszTypeName = SysAllocString(L"ForumEngine.ForumEngineUser");
                hr = pComServer->LoadAssembly(lpwszAssembly);
                if(!FAILED(hr))
                {
                    IDispatch* pdisp = NULL;
                    hr = pComServer->CreateNetInstance(lpwszTypeName, &pdisp);
                }
                SysFreeString(lpwszAssembly);
                SysFreeString(lpwszTypeName);
            }
            CoUninitialize();
        }
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA(e.what());
        throw;
    }
}

COM Server registry entries:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{467e7566-bef4-4138-a619-035d3171afcf}\1.0
    @ = NetComServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{467e7566-bef4-4138-a619-035d3171afcf}\1.0\0\win64
    @ = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\netcomserver\ComInprocServer\lib\NetComServer.tlb
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{467e7566-bef4-4138-a619-035d3171afcf}\1.0\FLAGS
    @ = 8
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{467e7566-bef4-4138-a619-035d3171afcf}\1.0\HELPDIR
    @ = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\netcomserver\ComInprocServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{e62a1cb0-86a7-40ae-afe4-75562c32a498
    @ = IComServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{e62a1cb0-86a7-40ae-afe4-75562c32a498}\ProxyStubClsid32
    @ = {00020424-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{e62a1cb0-86a7-40ae-afe4-75562c32a498}\TypeLib
    @ = {467e7566-bef4-4138-a619-035d3171afcf}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{e62a1cb0-86a7-40ae-afe4-75562c32a498}\TypeLib
    Version = 1.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
    @ = NetComServer.ComServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
    AppID = {c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}\LocalServer32
    @ = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\netcomserver\ComLocalServer\ComLocalServer.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}\ProgId
    @ = NetComServer.ComServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}\Version
    @ = 1.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}\TypeLib
    @ = {467e7566-bef4-4138-a619-035d3171afcf}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\NetComServer.ComServer
    @ = NetComServer.ComServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\NetComServer.ComServer\CLSID
    @ = {c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
    @ = NetComServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
    AccessPermission =
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9}
    LaunchPermission =
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{c6819a04-046e-4ea2-9750-949760cb26f9
    RunAs = Interactive User

DCOM permissions:



Account
Permissions




BUILTIN\Administrators
local access, remote access, execute local, execute remote, activate local, activate remote


NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
local access, remote access, execute local, execute remote, activate local, activate remote


SELF
local access, remote access, execute local, execute remote, activate local, activate remote


NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
local access, execute local, activate local


NT AUTHORITY\Interactive
local access, execute local, activate local


BUILTIN\Users
local access, execute local, activate local



I also tried calling CoCreateInstance multiple times and setting the local server thread wait. But it had no effect.
Any ideas?

Note: the repository link will not allow this question to "Go the distance." Those who cannot follow that link (many good reasons why they cannot) will not be able to see the code and if you commit updates to the code in the future  those who can follow this link will have a hard time finding the version of the project that had the problem this question is asking about. Either will most likely make the question not useful. I recommend producing a [mre] and adding it to the question.

Your code in the link is way to complicated to be able to help (and to run actually). You should post a simple reproducible sample. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Here's the official sample https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/COMServerDemo and a reg-free one: https://github.com/smourier/RegfreeNetComServer
